# Page 404's depending on its position in 'urlpatterns' - why?

Tags: python, django, url, path, url-pattern

So I'm trying to render the page 'submit' which has a generic.CreateView which is correctly configured. This URL pattern renders fine:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from curate import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.SetListView.as_view(), name='set_list'),
    path('new/', views.ItemListView.as_view(), name='new_list'),
    path('<int:pk>/edit', views.ItemEditView.as_view(), name='item_edit'),
    path('<int:pk>/delete', views.ItemDeleteView.as_view(), name='item_delete'),
    path('submit/', views.SubmitItem.as_view(), name='submit_item'),
    path('<slug>/', views.ItemDetailView.as_view(), name='item_detail'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.ItemDeleteView.as_view(), name='item_detailPK'),
    path('<slug>/', views.SetDetailView.as_view(), name='set_detail'),
]
```

But for some reason, if the Submit view is elsewhere in the list, ie like below, as in it's below the ItemDetailView.as_view() url, then it won't render, it just 404's.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from curate import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.SetListView.as_view(), name='set_list'),
    path('new/', views.ItemListView.as_view(), name='new_list'),
    path('<int:pk>/edit', views.ItemEditView.as_view(), name='item_edit'),
    path('<int:pk>/delete', views.ItemDeleteView.as_view(), name='item_delete'),
    path('<slug>/', views.ItemDetailView.as_view(), name='item_detail'),
    path('submit/', views.SubmitItem.as_view(), name='submit_item'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.ItemDeleteView.as_view(), name='item_detailPK'),
    path('<slug>/', views.SetDetailView.as_view(), name='set_detail'),
]
```

The weird thing is, the ItemDetailView is rendering fine - this powers all of the items on my page?

Comment: Perhaps unrelated, but you have two urls with identical patterns `'<slug>/'`.

Comment: As well as the identical `<slug>/`, the `<int:pk>/` will never be used because it will be matched by `<slug>/`.

Comment: I use the PK view in a template to 'increment' through articles - as a 'next' view. It's temporary, but it works for now.

Comment: I think you're mistaken, and that a request to `/5/` would be matched by `ItemDetailView` with `slug=5` rather than `ItemDeleteView` with `pk=5`. In any case, there is a mismatch between `Item*Delete*View` and `name='item_*detail*PK'` which you should check.

Answer (score 2):

```
path('<slug>/', views.ItemDetailView.as_view(), name='item_detail'),
path('submit/', views.SubmitItem.as_view(), name='submit_item'),
```

When `item_detail` is above `submit_item`, the request to `/submit/` is matched by the `'<slug>/'` so the request is handled by `ItemDetailView`.

You don't have an item with `slug="submit"`, so this gives a 404.

The Django URL resolver uses the first URL pattern that matches. It doesn't try other URL patterns if the first match returns a 404.

When `submit_item` is above `item_detail`, the request to `/submit/` is correctly handled by the `SubmitItem` view.

Comment: Thanks - that's really obvious but my head couldn't figure. Rather than re-write the code, I can just move the order of the url patterns around so the logic works. There's probably a better way to structure things, but this works. Thanks!

Comment: Your choices are to choose a suitable order for your URL patterns, or adjust the paths so that they don't clash (e.g. you could use `'by_slug/<slug>/'` so that it doesn't clash with `'submit/'`

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the url pattern - `<slug>/`. If this pattern is above the `submit`, then django tries to find the `slug=submit`. And since that doesn't exist in database, you get a 404.